# How to nicely display the user time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I would like to display the user's time zone.

```
@user.time_zone will display the city name "Brussels"
```

How could I get the full time zone with GMT like this :

```
(GMT+01:00) Brussels
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the trick

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[@user.time_zone]
```

display the full user time zone

```
(GMT+01:00) Brussels
```

Comment: Your topic title doesnt represent your question.